# Replace particular text strings with colname in dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two columns called Apple and Pear.
If the text in these columns say "Yes" or "No", I want this text to be replaced with the column name.
The desired result is shown in the fields Apple2 and Pear2 in the example.

```
Apple<-c("Yes","No",  "Yes",  "Other",  NA)
Pear<-c("Yes",NA,    "No",    "Other","Yes")
Apple2<-c("Apple","Apple","Apple","Other",NA)
Pear2<-c("Pear",NA,"Pear","Other","Pear")

data<-data.frame(Apple,Pear,Apple2,Pear2, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Can anyone suggest a way of achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `dplyr`, `across`, it can be done by getting the column name i.e. `cur_column()` with a conditional expression in `ifelse/case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
data <- data %>%
    mutate(across(c(Apple, Pear),  
       ~ case_when(.x %in% c("Yes", "No") ~ cur_column(), TRUE ~ .x)))
```

-output

```
data
  Apple  Pear Apple2 Pear2
1 Apple  Pear  Apple  Pear
2 Apple  <NA>  Apple  <NA>
3 Apple  Pear  Apple  Pear
4 Other Other  Other Other
5  <NA>  Pear   <NA>  Pear
```

Answer (score 2):

My answer is conceptually the same as @akrun's. What's different is that I assume your input `data` only has two columns. Therefore in your `across`, you need to use `.names` to set the column names of newly created ones. Also, we need to specify what to do if `.x == "Others"` in `case_when`.

```
library(dplyr)

Apple<-c("Yes","No",  "Yes",  "Other",  NA)
Pear<-c("Yes",NA,    "No",    "Other","Yes")
data<-data.frame(Apple,Pear)

data %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), 
                ~case_when(.x == "Other" ~ "Other",
                           .x %in% c("Yes", "No") ~ cur_column(),
                           TRUE ~ NA_character_), 
                .names = "{.col}2"))

  Apple  Pear Apple2 Pear2
1   Yes   Yes  Apple  Pear
2    No  <NA>  Apple  <NA>
3   Yes    No  Apple  Pear
4 Other Other  Other Other
5  <NA>   Yes   <NA>  Pear
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option using `imap_dfr` from `purrr`:

```
library(tidyverse)

imap_dfr(data, ~ replace(.x, .x %in% c("Yes", "No"), .y))
```

**Output**

```
  Apple Pear  Apple2 Pear2
  <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr>
1 Apple Pear  Apple  Pear 
2 Apple NA    Apple  NA   
3 Apple Pear  Apple  Pear 
4 Other Other Other  Other
5 NA    Pear  NA     Pear
```

Or another option using `transmute`:

```
data %>%
  transmute(across(everything(), ~ ifelse(
    .x %in% c("Yes", "No"), deparse(substitute(.)), .
  )))
```

**Data**

```
data <- structure(list(Apple = c("Yes", "No", "Yes", "Other", NA), Pear = c("Yes", 
NA, "No", "Other", "Yes"), Apple2 = c("Apple", "Apple", "Apple", 
"Other", NA), Pear2 = c("Pear", NA, "Pear", "Other", "Pear")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```